# For loop in python not executing for the entire range, it execute just once. I am stuck for 3 hours

Tags: python, for-loop

The for loop `for ttl in xrange(1,MAX_HOPS):` in `get_route` function is executing just once. it is supposed to run for values in range 1 to 30. I am posting my entire code. Please help.

```
import socket
import os
import sys
import struct
import time
import select
import binascii
ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST = 8
MAX_HOPS = 30
TIMEOUT  = 2.0
TRIES    = 2



def checksum(str):
    csum = 0
    countTo = (len(str) / 2) * 2
    count = 0
    while count < countTo:
        thisVal = ord(str[count+1]) * 256 + ord(str[count])
        csum = csum + thisVal
        csum = csum & 0xffffffffL
        count = count + 2
    if countTo < len(str):
        csum = csum + ord(str[len(str) - 1])
        csum = csum & 0xffffffffL
    csum = (csum >> 16) + (csum & 0xffff)
    csum = csum + (csum >> 16)
    answer = ~csum
    answer = answer & 0xffff
    answer = answer >> 8 | (answer << 8 & 0xff00)
    return answer


def build_packet():
    # Header is type (8), code (8), checksum (16), id (16), sequence (16)
    myChecksum = 0
    ID = os.getpid() & 0xFFFF
    # Make a dummy header with a 0 checksum.
    # struct -- Interpret strings as packed binary data
    header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, myChecksum, ID, 1)
    data = struct.pack("d", time.time())
    # Calculate the checksum on the data and the dummy header.
    myChecksum = checksum(header + data)
    # Get the right checksum, and put in the header
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        myChecksum = socket.htons(myChecksum) & 0xffff
        #Convert 16-bit integers from host to network byte order.
    else:
        myChecksum = socket.htons(myChecksum)
    header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, myChecksum, ID, 1)
    packet = header + data
    return packet

def get_route(hostname):

    timeLeft = TIMEOUT
    for ttl in xrange(1,MAX_HOPS):
        for tries in xrange(TRIES):
            destAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
            #Fill in start
            # Make a raw socket named mySocket
            try:
                mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.getprotobyname("icmp"))
            except socket.error, (errno, msg):
                if errno == 1:
                    raise socket.error(msg)
            #Fill in end
            mySocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_TTL, struct.pack('I', ttl))
            mySocket.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
            try:
                d = build_packet()
                mySocket.sendto(d, (hostname, 0))
                t = time.time()
                startedSelect = time.time()
                whatReady = select.select([mySocket], [], [], timeLeft)
                howLongInSelect = (time.time() - startedSelect)
                if whatReady[0] == []: # Timeout
                    print "*    *    * Request timed out."

                recvPacket, addr = mySocket.recvfrom(1024)
                print addr
                timeReceived = time.time()
                timeLeft = timeLeft - howLongInSelect
                if timeLeft <= 0:
                    print "*    *    * Request timed out."
            except socket.timeout:
                continue
            else:
                #Fill in start
                # Fetch the icmp type from the IP packet
                unpackedPacket = struct.unpack_from("bbHHhd", recvPacket, 0)
                (request_code, request_type, checksum, packet_id, sequence, timeSent) = unpackedPacket
                #Fill in end

                if request_type == 11:
                    bytes = struct.calcsize("d")
                    timeSent = struct.unpack("d", recvPacket[28:28 + bytes])[0]
                    print " %d   rtt=%.0f ms %s" % (ttl,(timeReceived -t)*1000, addr[0])
                elif request_type == 3:
                    bytes = struct.calcsize("d")
                    timeSent = struct.unpack("d", recvPacket[28:28 + bytes])[0]
                    print " %d   rtt=%.0f ms %s" % (ttl,(timeReceived -t)*1000, addr[0])
                elif request_type == 0:
                    bytes = struct.calcsize("d")
                    timeSent = struct.unpack("d", recvPacket[28:28 + bytes])[0]
                    print " %d   rtt=%.0f ms %s" % (ttl,(timeReceived -timeSent)*1000, addr[0])
                    return
                else:
                    print "error"
                    break
            finally:
                mySocket.close()

get_route("www.google.com")
```

Comment: It can't be that `return` on the 9th line from the bottom, can it?

Comment: WOOHOO!!. Thanks, that was the issue. I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Ah ;-) A happy customer ;-) Thanks! Yes, I didn't even have to read all your code to spot it! Let's call it a typo, okay? ;-)